# Android Studio espresso test recorder - swipe events

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing, android-espresso-recorder

I've been playing around with the espresso test recorder and [reading the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html)

The documentation states:

> Interact with your device to start logging events such as “tap” and
>   “type” actions.

Is it possible to record swipe events like swiping on a view pager? I've been unable to find any examples of this being done, though I know it's still in beta.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, Espresso Test Recorder lacks in features like swipe events or starting from actual activity. Maybe that would be fixed in the nearest feature.

Nowadays, still more simple and less flaky way is to write Espresso tests.

This might be useful:https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/espresso-cheat-sheet-2.1.0.pdf

Hope it will help.

Comment: This link doesn't exist anymore. Use straight from Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know at the moment is to manually add that gesture to the generated test code.

```
onView(withId(R.id.xyz)).perform(swipeLeft());
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping the new espresso recorder would abstract this out though but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Recycler view particular item swap

    ViewInteraction recyclerView = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.rc_vehicle_list),
                withParent(withId(R.id.ll_vehicle)),
                isDisplayed()));
        recyclerView.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(3,swipeUp()));




 public static ViewAction swipeUp() {
        return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.CENTER_LEFT,
                GeneralLocation.CENTER_RIGHT, Press.FINGER);
    }
```